# Is EventDispatcher.initialize gone from AS3? 

Tags: flash

OK, I took suggestion given in comments and trying to convert this flash game to AS3.

The class looked like this before I converted it

```
package  
{
    import flash.events.EventDispatcher;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    public class eventsBroadcaster extends MovieClip
    {
        public var addEventListener:Function;
        public var removeEventListener:Function;
        public var dispatchEvent:Function;

        public function eventBroadcaster() 
        {
            EventDispatcher.initialize(this);
        }
    }
}
```

But then I had to get rid of all three :Functions as errors said they are conflicting. Looks like in the new flash.events.EventDispatcher, they are already there. The only error I get now is

1061: Call to a possibly undefined method initialize through a reference with static type Class.

If curious, original question was:
Trying simple flash game in AS2. New to flash development. I keep getting this error and my flash game pops up empty.

Comment: If you're new to Flash, I hope you have a good reason to be learning AS2 instead of starting at 3. AS3 is vastly superior! If you're locked in due to requirements, good luck!

Comment: Agreed. And this is coming from a guy who loved AS2 cause it was so loose in its error handling (my lazy ways got the best of me). Just dive into AS3 if you're just starting... it'll be worth it.

Comment: @Myk or @jpea, any comments on the question I have posted here after changes you suggested?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I occassionally see similar errors when my class functions need to be made explicitly public, which was a common coding style in AS2.